# Trying to implement two audio files on webpage

Tags: html, audio

I'm regretfully a total noob to html so I was hoping you could answer my question.

I'm trying to implement three audio files on my webpage but only one of the source files is playing. The buttons for the other files work, but they only play from the one source. Can you help me?

Here's the code:

```
<div class="sound1">
        <div style="text-align:center; width:100px; height:100px; margin-left:390px; margin-top:0px; background-repeat:no-repeat; "> 
            <button style="background-image:url(speaker_bakur.png); width:100px; height:100px; border:transparent;
                ; "margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px;" onclick="playPause();" ></button> 

                <audio id="Sound">
                <source src="" type="audio/wav" />
                <source src="" type="audio/ogg" />
                <source src="svartbakur-4.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
                </audio> 
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript"> 
                var myAudio=document.getElementById("Sound"); 

                function playPause()
                { 
                if (myAudio.paused) 
                myAudio.play(); 
                else 
                myAudio.pause(); 
                }

                </script>

                </div>

                </div><!--Div hyphenate-->


<div class="sound2">
                <div style="text-align:center; width:100px; height:100px; margin-left:390px; margin-top:0px; background-repeat:no-repeat; "> 
                <button style="background-image:url(speaker_likka.png); width:100px; height:100px; border:transparent;
                ; "margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px;" onclick="playPause();" ></button> 

            <audio id="Sound">
                <source src="" type="audio/wav" />
                <source src="" type="audio/ogg" />
                <source src="likka-6.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
            </audio> 
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var myAudio=document.getElementById("Sound"); 

            function playPause()
            { 
                if (myAudio.paused) 
                myAudio.play(); 
                else 
                myAudio.pause(); 
            }

            </script>

    </div>

    </div><!--Div hyphenate-->


<div class="sound3">
        <div style="text-align:center; width:100px; height:100px; margin-left:390px; margin-top:0px; background-repeat:no-repeat; "> 
            <button style="background-image:url(speaker_fiskimasi.png); width:100px; height:100px; border:transparent;
                ; "margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px;" onclick="playPause();" ></button> 

                <audio id="Sound">
                <source src="" type="audio/wav" />
                <source src="" type="audio/ogg" />
                <source src="fiskimasi-21.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
                </audio> 
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript"> 
                var myAudio=document.getElementById("Sound"); 

                function playPause()
                { 
                if (myAudio.paused) 
                myAudio.play(); 
                else 
                myAudio.pause(); 
                }

                </script>

                </div>

                </div><!--Div hyphenate-->
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to define the source file location for the other two source tags. `<source src="" type="audio/wav" /><source src="" type="audio/ogg" />`

Comment: Read this for more information. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-the-html-5-audio-element/

Comment: There are errors in your button style. Remove the extra ; and  "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to play the multiple audio from one single JavaScript function:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<title>aa</title>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
function playPause(x)
{ 
    var myAudio=document.getElementById(x); 
    if (myAudio.paused) 
    myAudio.play(); 
    else 
    myAudio.pause(); 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sound1">
    <div style="text-align:center; width:100px; height:100px; margin-left:390px; margin-top:0px; background-repeat:no-repeat; "> 
            <audio id="Soundx1">
                <source  src="XXXXX.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
            </audio> 
            <button style="background-image:url(speaker_bakur.png); width:100px; height:100px; border:transparent; margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px;" onclick="playPause('Soundx1');" ></button> 
     </div>
</div>
<div class="sound2">
            <div style="text-align:center; width:100px; height:100px; margin-left:390px; margin-top:0px; background-repeat:no-repeat; "> 
        <audio id="Soundx2">
        <source  src="XXXXX.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
        </audio> 
            <button style="background-image:url(speaker_likka.png); width:100px; height:100px; border:transparent; margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px;" onclick="playPause('Soundx2');" ></button> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sound3">
    <div style="text-align:center; width:100px; height:100px; margin-left:390px; margin-top:0px; background-repeat:no-repeat; "> 
            <audio id="Soundx3">
            <source  src="XXXXXX.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
            </audio> 
        <button style="background-image:url(speaker_fiskimasi.png); width:100px; height:100px; border:transparent; margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px;" onclick="playPause('Soundx3');" ></button> 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements with the same ID. You are also redefining the `playPause()` function every time. In general, you seem to have no idea what you're doing.

You'd be better off just adding the `controls` attribute to the `audio` tags.

Answer (score 0):

The player is looking for the id "Sound".

```
getElementById("Sound");
```

You have 3 `<audio id="Sound">`s

Try changin them to something like `<audio id="Sound1">` and `<audio id="Sound2">` etc

You'll need to update the player to reflect your new audio ids.

Comment: I tried changing them to <audio id="Sound1"> and <audio id="Sound2"> and var myAudio=document.getElementById("Sound1"); and var myAudio=document.getElementById("Sound2"); but there is no difference?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and found that your problem is related with the JavaScript Code you are using  to play the audio files and the way you define the audio tag as one single tag is bind with all mp3 files:

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:100px; height:100px; margin-left:390px; margin-top:0px; background-repeat:no-repeat; "> 
   <audio id="Soundx1">
     <source  src="XXXXXX.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
       </audio> 
     <button style="background-image:url(speaker_bakur.png); width:100px; height:100px; border:transparent; "margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px;" onclick="playPause();" ></button> 
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var myAudio1=document.getElementById("Soundx1"); 
        function playPause()
        { 
            if (myAudio1.paused) 
            myAudio1.play(); 
            else 
            myAudio1.pause(); 
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

So What I have changes:

1. Audio id= *Unique for each audio file*
2. Unique JavaScript object for each audio ID as 
   var myAudioXX=document.getElementById("_unique_id_");

This code does work will multiple mp3 files. Also you should be using one single JavaScript function to play all the files instead of an each func to play each file. IF you will use one single JavaScript function to play all files, you can pass ID tag by object reference and it will reduce to code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How would I go about using one single JavaScript function?

Comment: I hope you got the answer to your this problem, and if yes, please kindly accept as answer. About one single javascript func, please spend some time to try by yourself (as this will help you to learn) and if could not solve, post an question and let me know and I sure will help.